# Is watching animated cartoons allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, image, movies, tv, cartoon

Is watching animated cartoons allowed?

If the cartoon has an animated scene of kissing, can I watch it? Should my kids be allowed to watch cartoons? I know that making images is haraam in islam (90% of people don't follow that) but I also heard that videos are allowed, since they are stored in electromagnetic form. Is that correct?

Comment: i can't believe there's even a possibility that some disney film like frozen, tangled, lion king or pocahontas is haram. or some other animated stuff like anime, spongebob, shrek, etc. it's just disney! it's just anime/cartoons! what is going on here? i'm not saying every single episode, scene, etc is halal but is producing or watching animated fiction generally or inherently haram?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, general ruling is not to draw or take picture of living beings. But in case of animated film, it is allowed if it is being in specific Islamic limits. As you said kissing scenes are there, so that's definitely a NO. Animations should not have any sort of nudity, mixing girls and boys openly or music in it. other than that it is allowed.

For detailed reference,you can go to: http://islamqa.info/en/71170

Comment: i can't believe there's even a possibility that some disney film like frozen, tangled, lion king or pocahontas is haram. or some other animated stuff like anime, spongebob, shrek, etc. it's just disney! it's just anime/cartoons! what is going on here? i'm not saying every single episode, scene, etc is halal but is producing or watching animated fiction generally or inherently haram?

Answer (score 1):

It's not haram. It's a cartoon and there is no indication from those who have created this cartoon that one is supposed to worship it.

Notably you say nothing about tv programmes which involve animated pixels. The same goes for this.

As for the specific mores on display, this will depend upon the country where the cartoon was created and where it's shown. Since cartoons are generally for children there is generally little haram content.

Answer (score 0):

It is haram to see bad since but if you have a kid you should if he is 5 years old or 7 let him watch some time if haram since come change the channel if he is little then then.q